# How to change the value of <p:dataTable> dynamically based on <p:selectOneButton>?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have 3 data lists of different types and I would like to display them in a single `<p:dataTable>` depending on the `<p:selectOneButton>` pressed like this:

- if the user clicks on "Button 1", I want to display `list1` in `<p:dataTable>`
- if the user clicks on "Button 2", I want to display `list2` in `<p:dataTable>`

Here's the view:

```
<p:selectOneButton value="#{managedBean.perspective}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Button 1" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Button 2" itemValue="2" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Button 3" itemValue="3" />
    <f:ajax event="change" render="table" />
</p:selectOneButton>

<p:dataTable id="table" value="#{managedBean.list}" var="object">
    <p:column headerText="title">
        ...
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Here's the model:

```
private List<Object1> list1 = new ArrayList<Object1>();
private List<Object2> list2 = new ArrayList<Object2>();
private List<Object3> list3 = new ArrayList<Object3>();
```

How can I reuse the same `<p:dataTable>` for different lists of objects?

Comment: your question is very unclear..

Comment: I cleaned up some Engrish. I think this is what you're ultimately asking, right?

Comment: thank you very much my friend!
sorry for the inconvenience

my english is so poor :[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to have a collection of object's properties so that you can use [`<p:columns>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf) to dynamically generate columns.

E.g.

```
<p:selectOneButton value="#{bean.type}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Button 1" itemValue="1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Button 2" itemValue="2" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Button 3" itemValue="3" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.change}" update="table" />
</p:selectOneButton>

<p:dataTable id="table" value="#{bean.list}" var="object">
    <p:columns value="#{bean.properties}" var="property">
        #{object[property]}
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

with

```
private static final List<String> OBJECT1_PROPERTIES = Arrays.asList("property1", "property2", "property3");
private static final List<String> OBJECT2_PROPERTIES = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar");
private static final List<String> OBJECT3_PROPERTIES = Arrays.asList("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5");

private List<Object1> list1 = new ArrayList<Object1>();
private List<Object2> list2 = new ArrayList<Object2>();
private List<Object3> list3 = new ArrayList<Object3>();

private String type;
private List<?> list;
private List<String> properties;

public void change() {
    if ("1".equals(type)) {
        list = list1;
        properties = OBJECT1_PROPERTIES;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you! I think this is the ideal solution for my problem.
I'll test it!

Answer (score 0):

Add valueChangeListener for `p:selectOneButton` :

Listener example:

```
public void yourListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    String newValue = (String) event.getNewValue();

    if ("1".equals(newValue){
        list = list1;
    } else if ("2".equals(newValue){
        list = list2;
    }else if ("3".equals(newValue){
        list = list3;
    }
}
```

and set for `p:selectOneButton` :

```
   <f:ajax update="table" />
```

Comment: the problem is that the "lists" are different signatures (type) list<objet1>, list<objet2> ...

Comment: So you can make list of type `Object` or create common interface for `Objet1`, `Objet2`, `Objet`3